# How to multiply in the same column sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table three columns Locations, Count Location, Table from. How can I multiply (Count Location) and then divide it to get the percentage.

Example:  Trying to Divide both location that are in the same Column! and then Multiple by 100 `(Count Location / Count Location)*100`

```
    Atlanta, GA 6   CL Table
    Atlanta, GA 20  TW Table
    The result  (6/20)*100=30%  


|Location     |Count Location|  Table From|
-------------------------------------------
  Atlanta, GA   6                CL Table
  Atlanta, GA   20               TW Table
  Austin, TX    27               TW Table
  Austin, TX    5                CL Table
  Chicago, IL   6                CL Table
  Chicago, IL   19               TW Table
  Corona, CA    6                CL Table
  Corona, CA    50               TW Table
  Dallas, TX    37               TW Table
  Dallas, TX    3                CL Table
  Denver, CO    3                CL Table
  Denver, CO    19               TW Table
  Houston, TX   21               TW Table
  Houston, TX   11               CL Table
```

Is there are way to do this for all locations and show the results in a new column next to them? Or do I need to make a new table to make it easier?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions appropriately.  And, what does 30% have to do with 6 and 20?

Comment: sorry for that, let me know if it is understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I see.  You want the CL percentage of TW.  You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (100 * max(case when tablefrom = 'CL Table' then count end) over (partition by location)/
        max(case when tablefrom = 'TW table' then count end) over (partition by location)
       ) as percentage
from table t;
```

If you just want the result per location (which makes more sense to me) just use aggregation:

```
select location,
       (100 * max(case when tablefrom = 'CL Table' then count end) /
        max(case when tablefrom = 'TW table' then count end)
       ) as percentage
from table t
group by location
```

Comment: I guess that will work for classification by   From Table, and if understood he wanted a classification by Location whis is the first coluln. So maybe he had to use the WITH Statement !!

Comment: ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 3: ...00 * max(case when "Table From" = 'CL Table' then count end)...
                                                             ^

Comment: i have gotten the error on top. when i try the query. I see the logic be-hide this query though and looks good.

Comment: ok sorry was not working in my PostgreSQL but it did work in zoho..SO im HAPPY!!!!!!!!  :)